# How to insert data into a table in android using sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, fragment

I am trying to insert a value into a SQLite database. I have two tables in the database but the value is not getting inserted into my second table i.e mynum table. I have used the same codes for insertion into the first table but it doesn't work for the second table. How can i fix this?
Here's my code

Databasehandler.java

```
public class Databasehandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final String LOGCAT = null;

    public Databasehandler(Context applicationcontext) {
        super(applicationcontext,"androidsqlite.db", null, 4);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Log.d(LOGCAT,"Database Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String query,query1;    
        query = "CREATE TABLE userlogin ( phoneId INTEGER PRIMARY  KEY,
                                   username TEXT,userid INTEGER,contacts INTEGER)";

        query1 = "CREATE TABLE mynum ( Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,num INTEGER)";
        db.execSQL(query1);
        db.execSQL(query);
        //db.execSQL(query1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String query,query1;
        query  = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS userlogin";
        query1 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mynum";
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.execSQL(query1);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void communityfragment(HashMap<String, String> queryvalues) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values    = new ContentValues();
        values.put("num",queryvalues.get("number"));
        database.insert("mynum", null, values);
        database.close();
    }
```

And here's my CommunityFragment.java class

```
public class CommunityFragment extends Fragment {
    HashMap<String, String> d=new HashMap<String, String>();
    d.put("number",f);
    //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email","abc"));
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"incommunityfragment"+d,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.communityfragment(d);

}
```

Comment: are you getting any error???

Comment: Fix the indentation please.

Comment: I am not getting any error the problem is thati think the communityfragment function is not getting called

Comment: Add some code around where you're calling db.communityfragment() - the one you've now showing won't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

your second field datatype is INTEGER and you are passing it the string. correct that.

you define num as integer

```
CREATE TABLE mynum ( Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,num INTEGER)
```

but you are giving it string.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Column types in sqlite are just suggestions; any column can contain any type of data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQLiteDatabase db    = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("Messsage", msg);
values.put("Name", SenderName);
values.put("GroupName", Groupname);
db.insert("TableName", null, Values);
```